# Change device Function Summary for Teensy-LC

Tags: usb, teensy

I found this thread here which describes procedure to change the produce-name of Teensy
However when we open device properties we see 'Teensy USB Serial (COM xx) in the Device function summary.

Please find the image below to understand what I am referring to.

[image: Teensy Device Properies]

So is there any way to change this details as well?

Comment: I think that string is inside the USB code in the Teensy. Conceivably you could locate the appropriate library and change it.

Comment: Could this string be inside the Teensy bootloader and presented to the USB device layer (Windows) when waiting for upload? In that case I don't think it is possible to change as the Teensy bootloader is not open-source.

Comment: Could you link or give the URL of the "thread" you found? Thank you.